# How to store other languages (unicode) in cookies and get it back again

Tags: javascript, cookies, unicode, utf-8

Can anyone help me understand how to store a cookie value that is in another language and than 
how to retrieve it again in that language.

I seem to have my foreign language cookies turn to garbage when retrieved after being stored.

Some code:

Write cookie code:

```
   function writecook() {
            document.cookie = "lboxcook=" + document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
            //input[0] is the input box who's value is stored
   }
```

Retrieve Cookie code:

```
  <script language="JavaScript"> 
            function get_cookie ( cookie_name )
            {
               var results = document.cookie.match ( '(^|;) ?' + cookie_name + '=([^;]*)(;|$)' );


               if ( results )
               return ( unescape ( results[2] ) );
               else
               return null;
            }
            </script>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `encodeURIComponent()` when setting the cookie and `decodeURIComponent()` when retrieving it.

```
var cookieValue = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
document.cookie = "lboxcook=" + encodeURIComponent(cookieValue);

function get_cookie(cookie_name) {
    var results = document.cookie.match ('(^|;) ?' + cookie_name + '=([^;]*)(;|$)');
    return results ? decodeURIComponent(results[2]) : null;
}
```

Comment: huge +1 this saved hours of work. Using jquery.cookie plugin.