# How to save a cookie value in unicode encoding

Tags: javascript, cookies, unicode

I am from Vietnam (we use special characters).
I would like to save a **cookie value** in **unicode** encoding to preserve those special characters, but I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 6):

*Quốc Ngữ* characters can be represented in **Unicode** - in consequence, you may use the`encodeURIComponent()` function to **set** the cookie content, and then the`decodeURIComponent()` function to **get** the original value back.

There's a neat post here about this, [How to store other languages (unicode) in cookies and get it back again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901633/how-to-store-other-languages-unicode-in-cookies-and-get-it-back-again).